# How to upgrade the Node version to very latest using Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04

I need to upgrade the latest version of Node.js in my Ubuntu system. Is this latest version user-friendly ? I need the command to upgrade it using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Look at this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version It will show you how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you install nodejs through nvm (node version manager), this way you can have various version at one time and can easily change what version you want

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

installing latest node should just be like this

```
nvm install node
```

or to install specific version

```
nvm install v4.5.0
```